Power Automate - Excel to Excel
I'm a new user to MS Power Automate.
I've been trying to get data in an excel table to copy over to another excel table. It needs to check if the data already exists using the ID column, if it does, then it needs to update the row, this is the problem I'm having.
Apologies if this is an obvious answer, but its taking me weeks to figure out. Can anyone help please?
I have the attached flow currently which tests ok but it only copies rows to the other table, it won't check if the row already exists or update the pre-existing rows based on the ID column.



Can you provide the output JSON for the List row present in a table and List row present in a table 1 operations?  Your condition isn't right but if you want a proper answer, that data will need to be supplied.  If you can provide it, edit your question and include it for both steps.

you should use 'Filter array' instead of 'Condition':


where:

'Apply to each - update rows' from parameter: outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']
Filter Array rows to update:

from: "@outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']"
where: "@equals(item()?['ID'],items('Apply_to_each_-_updadte_rows')?['ID'])"


Filter Array rows to add:

from: "@outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']"
where: "@not(contains(item()?['ID'],items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']))"



